# boolean cant be set on multiple objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

Again its time for the exams, so i'm here and got again a few little problems with my code.

My goal is, beeing able to switch blocks on buttonpress (works absolutely fine), and now i added a trigger which will set a boolean on false, so i cant move those blocks anymore. This works too...but only on the last set Block i want to move.

i used (as normal?):

`movingBlocks = GameObject.Find("SwitchableCube").GetComponent<MovingBlocks>();`

to get the access to the script i need to switch. I tried changing the variable via function and by simply changing it.
Is there anything within Unity or C# that does not allow setting a single Variable at multiple Objects?

thanks for all your help

(if i missed any thread where the solution was posted, im sooo sorry, but i was really unsure what i had to cover in my search)

EDIT:
`void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("DeadZone"))
        {
            movingBlocks.canSwitch = false;
            Debug.Log("Did enter");
            Debug.Log (movingBlocks.canSwitch);
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerExit()
    {
            movingBlocks.canSwitch = false;
        Debug.Log("probably set it on true again...without any reason");
    }`

thats exactly the code that changes variables, right now

Comment: Could you post the code where you set the boolean? I might be able to help, but I need to determine if this is a Unity-specific thing (since I haven't used it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find only returns one object, not multiple. Try using [FindObjectsOfType](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html)

```
MovingBlocks[] movingBlocks = FindObjectsOfType<MovingBlocks>();
```

This also means you need to iterate over all of them to change the canSwitch variable for all of them.

```
foreach (MovingBlocks m in movingBlocks)
     m.canSwitch = false;
```